# Read a directory as []byte without zipping it

Tags: arrays, go, directory, zip, grpc

I am experimenting `grpc` for transferring large files and directories from server to clients. When I transfer a directory, I use the `zip` package to create a zip writer to create an archive of the directory, which is then transferred using grpc.

```
zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
```

This works, but I was wondering if there's any convenient way to read a directory and its contents (files and sub-directories) into a []byte array for transfer over the wrire.

Comment: [path.filepath.Walk()](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) if directory `mkdir`; if file `save it`.

Comment: and for the fun of it without grpc [http.FileServer()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) - get root, parse html, get all <a> tags - which represent files and directories, if name ends with `/` it's a directory "GET" it and parse again, otherwise its a file so "GET" it. This will choke if there is index.html somewhere.... have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are free to use anything that implements `io.Writer` interface as destination of your zip archive [zip.NewWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#NewWriter)

If you want it to be stored into byte slice and do not know the size of it beforehand I would suggest to use `bytes.Buffer` as your destination:

```
buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
zip.NewWriter(buffer)
... do anything you need
resultBytesSlice := buffer.Bytes()
```